# Select last value from Json array

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to get the last item in an array from a JSON format. I have this JSON.

```
  @json =   
  N'{ 
        "solution": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "options": [
            {
                "choice_id": 205073,
                "choice": "aaaa"
            },
            {
                "choice_id": 205074,
                "choice": "bbbb"
            },
            {
                "choice_id": 205075,
                "choice": "cccc"
            },
            {
                "choice_id": 205076,
                "choice": "dddd"
            }
        ],
    }'
```

And I would like to get

```
  @json =   
  N'{ 
        "solution": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "options": {
              "choice_id": 205076,
              "choice": "dddd"
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve that result?

Comment: With 4k reputation, you should already be fairly familiar with [ask] - You need to show us what you've tried.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's the point, I havent tried anything because I dont know how to.... This JSON thing in sql is pretty new to me and I couldnt find any info that can help me to achieve that.

Comment: Well, you should probably start by [reading the documentation...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I did it, couldnt find anything related to what I want to achieve

Comment: How do you know you want the record with `"choice": "dddd"`?

Comment: @digital.aaron because is the last one in the array. It would be somthing like `array[array.length -1]` in javascript

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to take this into account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) =   
N'{ 
    "solution": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "options": [
        {
            "choice_id": 205073,
            "choice": "aaaa"
        },
        {
            "choice_id": 205074,
            "choice": "bbbb"
        },
        {
            "choice_id": 205075,
            "choice": "cccc"
        },
        {
            "choice_id": 205076,
            "choice": "dddd"
        }
    ]
}';

SELECT TOP 1 
         A.solution
        ,JSON_QUERY(B.[value]) AS options
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (solution nvarchar(max), options NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.options) B
ORDER BY B.[key] DESC
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

The result

```
{"solution":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
,"options":{
            "choice_id": 205076,
            "choice": "dddd"
           }
}
```

### Some explanation

`FROM OPENJSON` will dive into your JSON and find the *top-level* elements. We fetch `solution` *as is* and we state `AS JSON` for `options` to specify, that this value will be treated as JSON later on.

The `CROSS APPLY` will call `OPENJSON` again, but this time against the `options` and we will get an array back. The column `key` is the ordinal position within the array, so we can use `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY key DESC` to get the last element in the array.

Before we can re-assemble this query to a JSON we have to wrap `B.value` with `JSON_QUERY()`. Otherwise we would see escaped characters like `\t` or `\r\n` within the JSON. The reason: Without this, the JSON-string would not be taken as a JSON-string but as any other string and would be packed into the result as one single text value.

Answer (score 4):

You can either shred with OPENJSON and re-assemble the document FOR JSON (see @digital.aaron's answer), or use JSON_MODIFY, like this:

```
 declare @json nvarchar(max) =   
  N'{ 
        "solution": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "options": [
            {
                "choice_id": 205073,
                "choice": "aaaa"
            },
            {
                "choice_id": 205074,
                "choice": "bbbb"
            },
            {
                "choice_id": 205075,
                "choice": "cccc"
            },
            {
                "choice_id": 205076,
                "choice": "dddd"
            }
        ]
    }'  


declare @options nvarchar(max) = (
    select top 1 value 
    from openjson(@json,'$.options')
    order by [key] desc 
);

set @json = json_modify(@json, '$.options', json_query(@options))

select  @json
```

Outputs

```
{ 
        "solution": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "options": {
                "choice_id": 205076,
                "choice": "dddd"
            }
    }
```

Note that the [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function is also used for parsing a string into a JSON fragment.  Without that, the value in @options would be inserted as a single string value, instead of a json object.

Answer (score 2):

First, your JSON string is malformed. You need to remove the comma after the closing array bracket.

So let's declare our variable:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{ 
        "solution": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "options": [
            {
                "choice_id": 205073,
                "choice": "aaaa"
            },
            {
                "choice_id": 205074,
                "choice": "bbbb"
            },
            {
                "choice_id": 205075,
                "choice": "cccc"
            },
            {
                "choice_id": 205076,
                "choice": "dddd"
            }
        ]
    }'
```

Now you can use a combination of `OPENJSON()` and `FOR JSON` to get the last record in the array.

```
SELECT jsonfield = CAST((
                            SELECT TOP 1
                                j.solution
                                ,o.choice_id
                                ,o.choice
                            FROM
                                OPENJSON(@json)
                                WITH
                                (
                                    solution VARCHAR(MAX) '$.solution'
                                    ,options NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.options' AS JSON
                                ) j
                            CROSS APPLY
                                OPENJSON(options)
                                WITH
                                (
                                    choice_id INT '$.choice_id'
                                    ,choice VARCHAR(4) '$.choice'
                                ) o
                            ORDER BY o.choice_id DESC
                            FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
                        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

EDIT:

Or you can use this query, if you don't want to order by any of the node values:

```
SELECT jsonfield = CAST((
                            SELECT TOP 1
                                j.solution
                                --,o.*
                                ,c.choice_id
                                ,c.choice
                            FROM OPENJSON(@json)
                            WITH
                                (
                                    solution VARCHAR(MAX) '$.solution'
                                    ,options NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.options' AS JSON
                                ) j
                            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(options) o
                            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(o.Value) 
                            WITH (
                                    choice_id int '$.choice_id',
                                    choice varchar(4) '$.choice'
                                    ) c
                            ORDER BY [key] DESC
                            FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
                        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

Comment: There are some `APPLY`s superfluous, The `o` aliased one and the last one. In my answer you'll find how to use `JSON_QUERY` on `value` in order to use the object *as is*.