# JSON_VALUE path "$" returns NULL when it contains data

Tags: json, sql-server-2019

I have a column `data` consisting of `{"name":["John","Peter"],id:["20","30"]}`

If I do

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(data,'$.name[0]') from table
```

it returns `John` but doing

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(data,'$') from db
SELECT JSON_VALUE(data,'$.name') from table
```

returns `NULL` in both.

How come it does not return:

```
{"name":["John","Peter"],id:["20","30"]}
["John","Peter"]
```

Comment: `$.name` doesn't contain a scalar value, it contains an array. What are the actual results you are after here? If you simply want the JSON data, then don't use `JSON_VALUE`, just reference `data`. *(Also, I hope you don't have a table called `db`, that's a little confusing; a table isn't a database, a table is a database object.)*

Comment: I'm trying to extract the array of `name` (based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). Agreed with the `db`- I have changed it now for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) section of the `JSON_VALUE` documentation there is a table that says for `tags` array in the json says: Use **JSON_QUERY** instead.

```
SELECT json_query(j,'$.name') from a;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/121039/12)

Comment: Just what I needed - short question; do you know how to get the last element of an array, like `json_value(j,'$.name[-1]')' ?`

Comment: @CutePoison well, there is no straight forward solution for that but you can check this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703674/select-last-value-from-json-array)

Comment: That's a different question, @CutePoison , and should be posted as a new question but not difficult; though you would use `OPENJSON` rather than `JSON_QUERY()`.

Comment: Most simple answer, thanks