# GET last element of array in json column of my Transact SQL table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, json-query

Thanks for helping.

I have my table **CONVERSATIONS** structured in columns like this :

**[ ID , JSON_CONTENT ]**

In the column ID i have a simple id in Varchar

In the column JSON_CONTENT i something like this :

```
{
    "id_conversation" : "25bc8cbffa8b4223a2ed527e30d927bf", 
    "exchanges": [
        {
            "A" : "...",
            "B": "..."
        },
        {
            "A" : "...",
            "B": "..."
        },
        {
            "A" : "...",
            "Z" : "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to query and get the id and the **last** element of exchanges :

**[ ID , LAST_ELT_IN_EXCHANGE_IN_JSON_CONTENT]**

I wanted to do this :

```
select TOP 3 ID, JSON_QUERY(JSON_CONTENT, '$.exchange[-1]')
from CONVERSATION
```

But of course Transact SQL is not Python.

I saw theses answers, but i don't know how to applicate to my problem.

[Select last value from Json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703674/select-last-value-from-json-array)

Thanks for helping <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need an additional `APPLY` operator and a combination of `OPENJSON()` and `ROW_NUMBER()`. The result from the `OPENJSON()` call is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and when the JSON content is an array, the `key` column returns the index of the element in the specified array:

Table:

```
SELECT ID, JSON_CONTENT
INTO CONVERSATION
FROM (VALUES
  (1, '{"id_conversation":"25bc8cbffa8b4223a2ed527e30d927bf","exchanges":[{"A":"...","B":"..."},{"A":"...","B":"..."},{"A":"...","Z":"..."}]}')
) v (ID, JSON_CONTENT)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT c.ID, j.[value]
FROM CONVERSATION c
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT [value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key]) DESC) AS rn
   FROM OPENJSON(c.JSON_CONTENT, '$.exchanges') 
) j   
WHERE j.rn = 1
```

Result:

```
ID  value
------------------------
1   {
            "A" : "...",
            "Z" : "..."
    }
```

Notice, that `-1` is not a valid array index in your `path` expression, but you can access the item in a JSON array by index (e.g. `'$.exchanges[2]'`).